# Getting error The method add(EObject) in the type List<EObject> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf

```java
while( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Object obj = iter.next();
    URI uri = CommonResourceHelper.getInstance().getPlatformURI( adaptationID, adaptationID + getExtension( obj ) );
    Resource rsrc = rsrcSet.createResource( uri );
    rsrc.getContents().add( obj ); //getting error in this line
    CommonResourceHelper.getInstance().save( rsrc );
}
```

> Error: The method add(EObject) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: The method `add` accepts objects of type EObject. You're using `Object` as parameter. Does it tell you about anything?

Comment: You can't add something of type `Object` to a list which wants `EObject`. How is your iterator `iter` defined?